# Get dynamic id of textbox inside jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

My Dynamically created textbox ids

```
$.each(vendor_name, function(p, tt) { 
    tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" name="cmpny_id" id="cmpny_id"'+p+' value="'+vendor_name[p]+'"/>'));
    console.log('<input type="text" name="cmpny_id" id="cmpny_id"'+p+' value="'+vendor_name[p]+'"/>');
});
```

Now i want to get values of text boxes i have tried following codes

```
$(this).attr("cmpny_id"+[2])
```

Help me guys

Comment: Text box is a void element, and you are trying to set its innerHTML!!! what are you trying to do??

Comment: Ok i have editted @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: When do you want to get the values of these textboxes? What is the `this` in context? Do you want to receive an array of all the values? Do you want to receive the value of a specific input? Do you want to receive this information when? When you click on a button? Explain what you want to do.

Comment: try $(this).attr('id'); see more about attr() here http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Try referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232910/getting-the-value-of-dynamically-created-textbox-using-jquery

Comment: If you are using `.each ()` is because you already have the values in the array, why you are appending the `tr` in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample. You had a the closing quote for the input id in the wrong place, and your selector to find the input later was also incorrect.

```js
var p = 2;
var vendor_name = {};
vendor_name[p] = "some name";

// append a table cell with an input
$("#appendme").append($("<td>").html('<input type="text" name="cmpny_id" id="cmpny_id'+p+'" value="'+vendor_name[p]+'"/>'));

// display the value of cmpny_id2
alert($("#cmpny_id2").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="appendme"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what are trying to accomplish but you can try something like:

```js
var id = 0;

$(document).on('click','#addVendor',function() {
      $("#vendor_name").append('<tr><td>'+id+': <input type="text" name="cmpny_id"></td></tr>');
      id = id+1;
});

$(document).on('click','#getVendor',function() {
  if (id == 0) {
      alert('At least add one vendor');
  } else {
    $("input[name=cmpny_id]").each(function(index) {
      alert('Index: '+index+' Value= '+$(this ).val());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vendor_name">
</table>
<button id='addVendor'>Add Vendor Name</button>
<button id='getVendor'>Get Vendor Name</button>
```