# Javascript cannot see dynamically generated elements?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, element

I don't know why the newly generated elements can't be seen by next called function? Thanks for help!!
Solution: Add async: false to disable asynchronous feature to make sure test-output-2 and test-output-3 executed after birth process. By default, ajax uses async: true that is sth like multi-threading.

```
function birth(mom)
{
    $.ajax(
    {url: "/cgi-bin/count.cgi",   // return 3 for sure
     async: false,   // add this to disable asynchronous feature to make sure test-output-2 and test-output-3 executed after birth process
     success: function(xkids)     // xkids is 3
     {
         for( var i = 0; i < xkids; i++ )
         {
             mom.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
             mom.children[i].setAttribute("id", "child-"+i);
         }

         document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // now there are 3 children
     }
    });
     document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // there are 0 children if async: true

} 

var marry = document.getElementById("Marry"); // currently no child
birth(marry);

function whereIsTheChildren()
{
    document.getElementById("test-output-3").innerHTML = marry.children.length;   // there are 0 children if async: true
} 
whereIsTheChildren();
```

Comment: this could be of your help I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232910/getting-the-value-of-dynamically-created-textbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to locate an element in the DOM before it's loaded won't work (the script runs as soon as its encountered. If this is above the html in the file, the element wont exist yet and thus, wont be found)

Similarly, firing off an AJAX request and then acting as though this was a synchronous operation (waits for the operation to finish before executing more code) will not work.

In the first instance, the code is encountered before the browser has had time to parse the HTML, thus the element doesn't exist in the DOM when you try to get a reference to it - this can be fixed by waiting for the document to signal that it's completed loading.

The second issue is that immediately after firing the `birth` function, the `whereIsTheChildren` function is fired. Unfortunately, the ajax request is still pending and so we've not got the results back from it yet that we need to use. This is fixed by putting the call to `whereIsTheChildren` inside the success call-back for the ajax request.

I've whipped up a quick example, using vanilla JS and PHP - just substitute the request to the php file with the one for your CGI.

**getKidCount.php**

```
<?php
    echo "3";
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}

function myAjaxGet(url, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
            successCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("AJAX request failed to: " + url);
        errorCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    //birth(3, byId("Marry") );
    myBirth( byId('Marry') );
}

function myBirth(parentElem)
{
    myAjaxGet('getKidCount.php', onAjaxSuccess, onAjaxFail);

    function onAjaxSuccess(ajax)
    {
        var numKids = parseInt(ajax.responseText);
        for (var i=0; i<numKids; i++)
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = ("child-"+i);
            parentElem.appendChild(div);
        }
        document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = parentElem.children.length;   // now there are 3 children
        whereIsTheChildren();
    }
    function onAjaxFail(ajax)
    {
        alert("Ajax failed. :(");
    }
}

function whereIsTheChildren()
{
    document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = byId('Marry').children.length;   // there are 0 children
} 


/*
function birth(xkids, mom)
{
    for( var i = 0; i < xkids; i++ )
    {
        mom.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        mom.children[i].setAttribute("id", "child-"+i);
    }
    document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // now there are 3 children
} 

function birth(mom)
{
    $.ajax(
    {url: "/cgi-bin/count.cgi",   // return 3 for sure
     success: function(xkids)     // xkids is 3
     {
         for( var i = 0; i < xkids; i++ )
         {
             mom.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
             mom.children[i].setAttribute("id", "child-"+i);
         }

         document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // now there are 3 children
     }
     document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // now there are 0 children
} 
*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='test-output-1'></div>
    <div id='test-output-2'></div>
    <div id='Marry'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very thx, I just forgot to add that the birth process is in a call back function. The test-output-1 has children, but after the callback, there is no children anymore. I totally lose my mind. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidYoung -  The braces dont match in your updated birth function. The `{` that immediately precedes `url: ` is matched by the `}` that's under the opening  brace. Put another way, You're missing a `)` and a `}` at the end of that function. Software that highlights matching braces is useful for this - I use notepad++

Comment: Thx for pointing out. I found the problem is that the call back function is paralleled, so the afterwards statements don't wait for count.cgi&its callback to finish...In other words, when whereIsTheChildren() is called, the for statement may even not start executing.

Comment: No problem. Bingo! That's just what my edited solution says. It should be more helpful now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modified to represent in DOM as well is in console.log

```js
function birth(xkids, mom) {
  var mom = document.querySelector(mom);
  console.log('Mom: '+mom.id);
  for (var i = 0; i < xkids; i++) {
    mom.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    mom.children[i].setAttribute("id", "child-" + i);
    mom.children[i].innerHTML = mom.children[i].id;
  }
  console.log(mom.id+' has '+mom.children.length+' children');
  var test = document.createElement("output");
  document.body.appendChild(test);
  test.value = mom.id + ' ' + mom.children.length;
}

birth(3, '#Marry');
birth(5, '#Liz');
birth(2, '#Betty');
```

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
output {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
.mom {
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Marry" class="mom">Marry</div>
<div id="Liz" class="mom">Liz</div>
<div id="Betty" class="mom">Betty</div>
```

Comment: This example is cool, very thanks to illustrate this in a better way!

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks, you can upvote even though it wasn't the excepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you put this in window.onload event handler? your code is working, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tnL8gsL/)

```
window.onload=function(){
function birth(xkids, mom)
{
    for( var i = 0; i < xkids; i++ )
    {
        mom.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        mom.children[i].setAttribute("id", "child-"+i);
    }

    document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = mom.children.length;   // now there are 3 children
} 

var marry = document.getElementById("Marry"); // currently no child
birth(3, marry);

function whereIsTheChildren()
{
    document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = marry.children.length;   // there are 0 children
} 
whereIsTheChildren();
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply, I just tried, but still the whereIsTheChildren() shows 0 children...

Comment: @DavidYoung please share your fiddle, or update my fiddle so that I can see the output you are getting.

Comment: Sorry I neglected a very important part, the test-output-1 is in a callback function after a server request. Seems problems are here, but why?